# How to pass variable only if it is set in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use **CodeIgniter** form helper. I only want to pass the `$incident->street_id` variable if it is set. I don't want to use if so is there any way to reduce to one line probably cause it will just be a clutter if I use if else.

```
echo form_dropdown(
    'street',
    $streets,
    $incident->street_id,
    'class="form-control required"'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the ternary operator, which is basically a shorthand for `if/else`.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('street', $streets, isset($incident->street_id) ? $incident->street_id : '', 'class="form-control required"');?>
```

---

The syntax is as follows:

```
condition ? ture : false
```

Comment: Actually i'm familliar with it. Its just i thought it can only be used to assign value to a variable or echoing a variable. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
echo form_dropdown('street', $streets, isset($incident->street_id)?$incident->street_id:"else if it doesnt set", 'class="form-control required"');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo form_dropdown('street', $streets, isset($incident->street_id) ?:  'NULL', 'class="form-control required"');?>
```

Comment: You can pass anything in place of NULL as per the codeigniter documentation for form_dropdown helper